# ¿Se puede combinar los resultados de 3 tablas en 1?

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

Estoy extrayendo datos desde csv a postgres con python.
He utilizado copy_from para introducir los datos de 3 csv en 3 tablas postgres.
Ahora tengo que crear una 4 tabla que convine los resultados.
¿Habría forma de extraer una columna especifica de csv con copy_from para introducirlos en la nueva tabla?

Como ya tengo los datos en 3 tablas, estaba intentado lanzar una consulta que fusione los datos y los vuelque en la 4 tabla.

Si alguien pudiera aconsejarme para hacerlo de una forma sencilla y correcta.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Forma de hacerlo con copy_from:

```
    modelo = open(r'modelo.csv', 'r')
    cursor.copy_from(modelo, 'modelo', sep=';')
    connection.commit()
    print("Se han introducido correctamente los datos en la tabla Modelo")

    color = open(r'color.csv', 'r')
    cursor.copy_from(color, 'color', sep=';')
    connection.commit()
    print("Se han introducido correctamente los datos en la tabla Color")

    matricula = open(r'matricula.csv', 'r')
    cursor.copy_from(matricula, 'matricula', sep=';')
    connection.commit()
    print("Se han introducido correctamente los datos en la tabla Matricula")
```

Forma de hacerlo con dataframe:

```
 df =pd.read_csv('modelo.csv', header=None, names=["id", "modelo", "marca"])

    df2 = pd.read_csv('color.csv', header=None, names=["id", "idmodelo", "color"])

    df3 = pd.read_csv('matricula.csv', header=None, names=["id", "idmodelo", "matricula"])

    engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:pass@127.0.0.1:5432/bbdd')
    df.to_sql('modelo', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Comment: Intenta mostrar tu código, y lo que has intentado. Sería de utilidad para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No he trabajado con Postgres, pero SQL es standard para todos los DBMS, por lo que con este UPDATE deberías lograr tu cometido, la única exigencia para su ejecución es que tengas definida una FK en cada tabla para poder relacionarlas y claro como es un UPDATE en la tabla destino ya debería existir el campo indice para proceder con el UPDATE.

```sql
UPDATE
    Tabla_1 t1
INNER JOIN Tabla_2 t2 ON
    t1.id_t2 = t2.id 
SET
    t1.campo = t2.campo;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su aportación. No había tenido en cuenta las FK.  En mi caso quiero extraer una columna de cada tabla (modelo, color, matricula) en la tabla coche.  Lo he intentado de la siguiente manera pero no consigo una query valida: select modelo.modelo, color.color, matricula.matricula
from modelo INNER JOIN color on modelo.id = color.idmodelo
   INNER JOIN matricula on color.idmodelo = matricula.idmodelo
group by modelo.modelo